# Rank-1 Type requires Rank2Types extension

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, higher-rank-types, forall

[Haskell wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Rank-N_types) on Rank-N-Types tells that this type

```
forall a . a -> (forall b . b -> a)
```

has Rank 1. I believe in this fact and it seems quite understandable for me (keeping in mind what I already know about how to determine rank of function). However, when I'm trying to write next code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}

foo :: forall a . a -> (forall b . b -> a)
foo = undefined
```

it doesn't compile (ghc 8.0.1) resulting in next error:

```
• Illegal polymorphic type: forall b. b -> a
  Perhaps you intended to use RankNTypes or Rank2Types
• In the type signature:
    foo :: forall a. a -> (forall b. b -> a)
```

So I wonder: does `foo` type really have Rank-2? Or GHC just doesn't have some smart mechanism to detect true rank of function? Sometimes in educational purposes I want to have some `ghci` command like `rank` to inspect true ranks of function types...

```
ghci> :rank foo
foo :: forall a . a -> (forall b . b -> a)  -- Rank 1
```

Comment: In Haskell 98, `forall` is not a reserved symbol. To use it as an explicit quantifier requires one of those two language extensions, even if the types you want to write are rank 1. Rank 1 types usually have an equivalent form where the quantifiers can be left implicit, hence this issue: the expectation is that you switch on explicit `forall` only if you want to go higher than rank 1, where you really need it.

Comment: @pigworker I'm not using Haskell 98, I'm using Haskell 2010. And I enabled specific ghc extension `-XExplicitForAll`. I just expected this extension to work as something like hypothetical `-XRank1Types` where all `forall`'s should be lifted if possible. Apparently, latest ghc user guide doesn't have a word about such behaviour: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#explicit-universal-quantification-forall

Comment: The Haskell 2010 language is almost identical to Haskell 98. The newer standard includes more library functions and standardizes empty data declarations and pattern guards. If there are any other extensions to the language, per se, then they're very small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is documented in the [typechecker's `TcValidity` module](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/e0fe7c3131c4a18ddd9dd9f2afdd46cafc8cd7ae/compiler/typecheck/TcValidity.hs#L408).

```
Note [Higher rank types]
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Technically
            Int -> forall a. a->a
is still a rank-1 type, but it's not Haskell 98 (Trac #5957).  So the
validity checker allow a forall after an arrow only if we allow it
before — that is, with Rank2Types or RankNTypes
```

I'm not a good language lawyer but it seems [the Haskell 98 specification seems to prevent quantifiers](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5957) after any arrows, despite that that is a more stringent requirement than rank-1'd-ness. As Haskell 2010 only lightly updated the specification I believe this is applicable to 2010 as well.

I believe (but am not certain) the way GHC encodes this is with a `let r1 = LimitedRank True r0` in the `checkValidType` function, which specifies that `forall`s can appear at the beginning of a type declaration but subsequent function arguments must be rank zero, which precludes the `forall b. b -> a` in your type.

*standard disclaimer: i'm no expert, all i had was github search*

Comment: AFAIK `forall`-s to the right of `->` are floated to the top of the scope. They may appear in type annotations in a misleading manner. The actual type of `foo` is `forall a b. a -> b -> a`.